# Get all child of HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I use this code for add to `hashmap` :

```
static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> arrayMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("t");
list.add("b");
arrayMap.put(12, list);

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("y");
list.add("x");
arrayMap.put(18, list);
```

this code work correct

but i cant get child of `arrayMap` in foreach

```
for(arrayMap .... ){
     return // 12:t,b   18:y,x
}
```

My try :

```
for (int a = 0; a < arrayMap.size(); a++)
        {
            HashMap<String, Integer> tmpData = (HashMap<String, Integer>) arrayMap.get(a);
            Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
            Iterator it = key.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String hmKey = (String) it.next();
                Integer hmData = (Integer) tmpData.get(hmKey);

                System.out.println("Key: " + hmKey + " & Data: " + hmData);
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }

        }
```

Comment: When you say child do you mean the key-value pairs or just the values? Also, the values are lists, so do you mean to get each element of each list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `entrySet()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to iterate over the each entry in the HashMap in a nested loop like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : arrayMap.entrySet()){
   //entry.getKey() will be each key in the HashMap
    for(String str : entry.getValue()){
         // str is one entry of the ArrayList for that Key
    }
}
```